# React-Native animations dont work properly after setValue

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a list of items rendered in flatlist and I'm animating each of them.

In constructor I assign values for animations

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = { ... };

     this.height = new Animated.Value(SCREEN_WIDTH/1.8);   
     this.width = new Animated.Value(SCREEN_WIDTH/2.5);
}
```

So I render items by index to get different values of them like this:

```
renderStyle
if(index == 0){
            return {
                marginRight: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                marginLeft: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                margin: SCREEN_WIDTH / 50,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height,
                opacity: this.state.opacity,
                borderRadius: SCREEN_WIDTH / 36,
            }
        }

        if(index == 1){

            this.height.setValue(SCREEN_WIDTH/1.5);

            return {
                marginRight: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                marginLeft: SCREEN_WIDTH / 35,
                margin: SCREEN_WIDTH / 50,
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height,
                opacity: this.state.opacity,
                borderRadius: SCREEN_WIDTH / 36,
            }
        }
```

then I animate the items when user press on it. Index = 0 animates correctly but index = 1 which I set the new value is not animating at all, I dont understand whats wrong with it? Can you explain me please?

Animation function:

```
Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.width,{
                toValue: SCREEN_WIDTH/1.2,
                duration: 750
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.height,{
                toValue: SCREEN_HEIGHT/1.2,
                duration: 750
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 750
            }),
        ]).start(() => this.props.go(item));

        setTimeout(() => Actions.video({item: item}), 800);
```

Render

return

```
(
            <Animated.View pointerEvents={this.state.pointer} onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
                this.setState({
                    measurements: nativeEvent.layout
                })
            }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.captureAnimation.bind(this, item, index)}>
                    <AnimatedImage source={{uri: 'http://' + item.info.picture_path}} style={this.renderStyle(index)}/>

                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        );
```

This is a different JS file, so flatlist is working in home page and renderItem method gets the values in this JS file to be able to animate each of it.

Edit: I found a alternative solution but anyways its not still explaining why after set value animation is not working.

Comment: I think it has to do with your setting of `this.height` in the function. Does it work as you expect if you change your return value to use `height: SCREEN_WIDTH/1.5`?

Comment: yeah I tried like that, its not working as well..

Comment: Can you provide us a snippet of the render method, to be able to see where you use these values and how? My guess would be that you might be setting the height value during/after the animation, providing unwanted results. Another thing you could try is using the height as a state value, instead of a static property (You can animate it in the same way). Also, if the animation is kicked off by some gesture, that might have weird behaviour inside a FlatList.

Comment: ok let me just add the all render so you can understand it, because for me its very strange..